# Multithreaded Multiplication of Large Non-sparse, Non-square Matrices in C/C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, math, matrix, matrix-multiplication

All,

I'm looking for recommendations for C or C++ libraries (preferably open source) that use multi-threaded techniques to multiply large, non-square, (e.g. 65536xn in size where n < 65536) non-sparse matrices.  Thanks.

-&&

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intel MKL (not open source)

AMD ACML (free, but not open source)

GOTO BLAS (free for academic use, IIRC, and you get the source, but not "open source")

ATLAS BLAS (open source)

Comment: Using one of these BLAS libraries is definitely the way to go.  However, it is worth noting that there C++ libraries (e.g. [dlib](http://dlib.net) and [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net)) that layer a nicer interface on top of these somewhat painful to use C interfaces.

Comment: & Dave King:  I'll look into these.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [Intel Software](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/a-tale-of-two-algorithms-multithreading-matrix-multiplication/) folks seem to have a good discussion on the subject.